# plotly дифференцировать маркеры

Tags: python, pandas, графика, matplotlib, plotly

Я пытаюсь нарисовать график в plotly из CSV файла.

файл содержит строки типа:

```
frame.number,frame.time_relative,frame.interface_name
"1","0.000000000","enp0s31f6"
"2","0.286968124","enp0s31f6"
"3","0.347273802","enp0s31f6"
"4","0.376051415","enp0s31f6"
"5","1.895804954","enp0s31f6"
"6","2.039418070","enp0s31f6"
"7","2.061084575","enp0s31f6"
"8","3.026748561","enp0s31f6"
"9","3.247024689","enp0s31f6"
"10","3.896585252","eth0"
"11","4.001361629","enp0s31f6"
"12","4.216054934","eth0"
"13","4.269130040","enp0s31f6"
"14","4.269426650","eth0"
"15","4.463316773","enp0s31f6"
```

Я сделал всё вот так:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from datetime import datetime
import plotly.offline
import plotly.figure_factory as FF
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go


df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df.head()

trace1 = go.Scatter(
                    x=df['frame.number'], y=df['frame.time_relative'],
                    mode='markers+text', name='enpos31f6',
)
trace2 = go.Scatter(x=df['frame.number'], y=df['frame.time_relative'], 
                    mode='markers+text', name='wlans',
)

layout = go.Layout(title='Simple Plot from csv data',
                   plot_bgcolor='rgb(230, 230,230)')

fig = go.Figure(data=[trace1, trace2], layout=layout)
plotly.offline.plot(fig)
```

На выходе получил:
[image: вывод]

Как дифференцировать маркеры, чтобы всё что принадлежит `enp0s31f6` было синими маркерами, а `eth0` оранжевыми?. Сейчас они друг на друге.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решение с использованием plot.ly:

```
import plotly
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go


plotly.tools.set_credentials_file(username='DemoAccount', api_key='lr1c37zw81')

enpo = df.loc[df['frame.interface_name'].isin(['enp0s31f6'])]
eth0 = df.loc[df['frame.interface_name'].isin(['eth0'])]

trace1 = go.Scatter(
                    x=enpo['frame.number'], y=enpo['frame.time_relative'],
                    mode='markers+text', name='enpos31f6',
                    marker = dict(
                    size = 20,
                    color = 'blue',
                    line = dict(
                        width = 2,
                        color = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
                    )
    )
)
trace2 = go.Scatter(
                    x=eth0['frame.number'], y=eth0['frame.time_relative'],
                    mode='markers+text', name='eth0',
                    marker = dict(
                    size = 20,
                    color = 'orange',
                    line = dict(
                        width = 2,
                        color = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'
                    )
    )
)

data = [trace1, trace2]

layout = dict(title = 'My Scatter',
              yaxis = dict(zeroline = False),
              xaxis = dict(zeroline = False)
             )
fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig, filename='styled-scatter')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Пример решения без использования `plotly` - рисуем обычными средствами Pandas:

```
df.loc[df['frame.interface_name'].isin(['enp0s31f6']), 'color'] = 'b'
df.loc[df['frame.interface_name'].isin(['eth0']), 'color'] = 'orange'
```

график:

```
df.plot.scatter(x='frame.number', y='frame.time_relative', c=df['color'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]